# Display of duplicate records in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I am working on an online music store. There are buttons like <kbd>myplaylists</kbd>, <kbd>mydownloads</kbd> etc...
On clicking on these buttons, a list of songs appears accordingly in a grid view.

The problem is that when I click on the buttons twice quickly the list appears two times like 1..4..8 1..4..8 and if I click thrice quickly it happens three times.The function that displays the list uses `append()` to add songs to the list.

These things happen only on Firefox

I cannot figure out the problem.

```
function fillMyMusicSongGrid
{
// code to fetch data from the database
embedSongGrid(.....);//displays the grid
}

embedSongGrid(.....)
{
  //displays the grid
tableContent = '...............'
$(tableCont).appendTo('table#songList');
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the append function?

Comment: I think you should post your code, seems like you need to reset a variable somewhere before appending...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm guessing correctly, pressing these buttons makes and Ajax call back to the server to get the information, probably as a JSON array. You then loop through these and [`append()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/append) them to the appropriate div. Either that or you get HTML and just append it.

Simply solution: just [`empty()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/empty) it before you add it:

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  success: function(data) {
    $("#songlist").empty();
    for (song in data) {
      $("#songlist").append(...);
    }
  }
});
```

or

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  success: function(html) {
    $("#songlist").html(html);
  }
});
```

Comment: but why i doesnot happen if i click it slowly

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(tableCont).empty();
$(tableCont).appendTo('table#songList');
```

instead of

```
$(tableCont).appendTo('table#songList');
```